# Entity query returning duplicated records for everything

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've had issues with my query that I was finally able to work through, but now duplicate date is formed even with Distinct().  I know these joins are messy, unfortunately it's what I have to do since the tables I'm working with have no relationships between them.

```
try
            {
                //work on query further , need to get client ID correctly
                if (vehicleses.Count == 0)
                    return null;
                string siteId = QueryExportSiteWithId(exportSiteId).SiteId;
          //      db.Database.Log = Console.Write;

                var joinedInventorySettings = await (from id in db.Inventory_Descriptions
                    join iv in db.Inventory_Vehicles
                    on new {client = id.ClientID, id = id.InventoryID} equals new {client = iv.ClientID, id = iv.ID}
                    into descGroup
                    from m in descGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join se in db.Settings_Exports
                    on m.ClientID equals se.ClientID into settingGroup
                    from sg in settingGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join sl in db.Settings_Lots
                    on new {client = m.ClientID, id = m.LotID} equals new {client = sl.ClientID, id = sl.ID} into
                    lotsGroup
                    from lg in lotsGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join ses in db.Settings_ExportSites on new {client = m.ClientID, lotId = m.LotID, site = siteId}
                    equals new {client = ses.ClientID, lotId = ses.LotID, site = ses.Site} into exportGroup
                    from eg in exportGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join ifs in db.Inventory_Features
                    on new {client = m.ClientID, id = m.ID} equals new {client = ifs.ClientID, id = ifs.InventoryID}
                    into invFeatGroup
                    from ifg in invFeatGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join ip in db.Inventory_Photos
                    on m.ID equals ip.InventoryID into photo
                    from photos in photo.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where m.Archived != "1"
                          && m.Holding != "1"
                          && m.Status == "A"
                          && clientIdList.Contains(m.ClientID)

                    select new JoinedInventorySettings()
                    {
                        InventoryVehicles = m,
                        InventoryDescriptions = id,
                        SettingsExports = sg,
                        //InventoryPhotos = ,
                        SettingsLots = lg,
                        InventoryFeatures = ifg,
                        SettingsExportSites = eg
                    }).Distinct().ToListAsync();

                if (joinedInventorySettings != null)
                {
                    returnList.AddRange(joinedInventorySettings);
                    return returnList;
                }
                return null;
            }
```

Comment: You can (and should) define relationships in your entity model so you can can rid of these joins. Your issue is usually caused by primary keys (as known by Entity Framework) that are not actually *unique* identifiers.

Comment: @GertArnold  If i define relationships in the edmx file, will the heal some of the speed issues I'm having?  It looks like if I do that, I should split up the associations between the inventory and the settings as they don't share the same primary keys, they only share one together.

Comment: @gertarnold Whoops, I didn't mean speed, I meant the duplicates.  Every row has about 2-4 duplicates retrieved.

Comment: You first have to check whether the primary keys in the class model are really unique identifiers.

Comment: @gertarnold They aren't, but a client Id and an inventory Id together act as one.

Comment: Interesting, let me check that our right now!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is curious, I was able to fix the issue by grouping items by two of the entity keys that I know will be in the dataset.